# Excel cell values -automatic searching

Tags: excel

I need to do research. I have to copy values from excel cell(areound 500 values) into google (wiki) . Is it any way i could make it automatic. Convert excel cell values as search parameters. [cell value]+wiki

Comment: So you want something that formats the cell values as wiki links that could for instance be copied and pasted into a wiki page, or are you looking for a macro that opens 500 web pages at once with 500 different search results?  I don't really know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options;

1. If you know the wikiarticle exists

   =HYPERLINK("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" & A1)
2. If you want to go to the actual search engine of wiki because you are unsure

   =HYPERLINK("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" & A1)

In both of these cases I`ve assumed that the first column contains the search terms. You can then click on each link to get to the wiki search engine or article depending.